# Pipe not found when building in production mode

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-components, angular-pipe

I created an angular 6 app using angular-cli, added some modules and components to it, and also some pipes in a shared module.

I can successfully build my application using `ng build` and successfully run it using `ng serve`.

But when I try to build the exact same application using `ng build --prod` I'm getting the following error:

> The pipe 'myPipe' could not be found

I do declare and export the pipe in the SharedModule, and I import SharedModule from the module where I'm using the pipe. Is there something in addition I need to do for production mode? Note that the module where I'm using the pipe is lazy-loaded, so maybe that makes a difference.

---

As a side-note:
When building in production mode I'm also getting many errors regarding to font-awesome ("Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'", "'fa-icon' is not a known element"), which I don't get when building a non-production version. But I thought I'll address the pipe problem first.

Comment: Declaring, exporting your pipe in your SharedModule and importing SharedModule into your feature module should work, no matter if lazy loaded or not

Comment: since you are in Angular 6 did you try the following syntax : `ng run <appName>:build:<configName>` ?

Comment: I tried "ng run <appName>:build:production" and the build fails with the same problems.

Comment: @YoukouleleY I fixed it - thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake... I actually forgot to import my SharedModule in one of my other modules. The error message made me think the error is occuring in some different module.

The difference between production and non-production build is simple: The non-production build failed as well, but only at runtime - while the production build failed at build time.